# Syntax error in Join Operation- MS Access inline join statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run below query but I am getting error on MS Access, "Syntax error in Join Operation"

Below is my query -

```
        select 
    v.City,
    v.CURRENCY, 
    (
    select 
        Sum(VSDEH.NORM_PRICE_MEDIUM*BCIEH.WEIGHT_OR_MULTIPLIER) AS BaseMedium

        FROM (
        // This line has error ->> ([VSURVEYDATA] AS VSDEH INNER JOIN [BASKET_CONTENT_ITEMS] AS BCIEH ON VSDEH.ITEM = BCIEH.ITEM_ID) 
                      INNER JOIN  [EXCHANGE_RATES] AS EXREH  on VSDEH.SURVEY_DATE = EXREH.RATE_DATE AND VSDEH.CURRENCY = EXREH.BASE_CURRENCY_ID
                   )

        WHERE (
        VSDEH.SURVEY_DATE = v.SURVEY_DATE 
        AND BCIEH.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ID='ICOL' 
        AND BCIEH.BASKET_ID= b.BASKET_ID
        AND BCIEH.ITEM_ID not in ( '215','216','326')
        AND EXREH.HOST_CURRENCY_ID= ex.HOST_CURRENCY_ID
        AND EXREH.RATE_SET_ID=' '
        AND VSDEH.CITY in (v.City)
        )
        GROUP BY VSDEH.CITY, VSDEH.CURRENCY 

    ) as BaseMediumEH

        FROM ((
    ([VSURVEYDATA] AS VSDEH INNER JOIN [BASKET_CONTENT_ITEMS] AS BCIEH ON VSDEH.ITEM = BCIEH.ITEM_ID) 
    INNER JOIN  [EXCHANGE_RATES] AS EXREH  on VSDEH.SURVEY_DATE = EXREH.RATE_DATE AND VSDEH.CURRENCY = EXREH.BASE_CURRENCY_ID
    )

    INNER JOIN qSTAHostCity ON VSURVEYDATA.CITY = qSTAHostCity.HostCity)

        WHERE (
              v.SURVEY_DATE = [Survey Date]  
              AND b.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ID='ICOL' 
              AND b.BASKET_ID= [Basket ID]
              AND ex.HOST_CURRENCY_ID='USD'
              AND ex.RATE_SET_ID=' ')

        GROUP BY v.CITY, v.CURRENCY ORDER BY v.CITY
```

Can anyone suggest what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: remove `()` on that line. Also remove `()` after `from`

Comment: Don't be shy.  What is the error?  (Edit your question and add it in.)

Comment: this is the error - "Syntax error in Join Operation"

Comment: Access has a special sintax for subquerys, maybe that's the problem. Try to enclouse subquery between "[Your subquery].", dot included

Comment: @vkp I removed `()` and tried but still same

Comment: @ericpap, I am unsure where to put this.. could you please suggest.

Comment: how about replacing the condition `VSDEH.CITY in (v.City)` with `VSDEH.CITY = (v.City)`?

Comment: Tried `VSDEH.CITY = (v.City)` but no luck.

Comment: Is this the actual query you are using? You are using prefixes that don't match any alias, for example `v.SURVEY_DATE`, yet there is no table with an alias `b`. The same applies for the aliases `b`, and `ex`. Finally, I don't think you even need a correlated subquery, I think you could replace this with ----  `SUM(IIF(BCIEH.ITEM_ID NOT IN ( '215','216','326'),VSDEH.NORM_PRICE_MEDIUM*BCIEH.WEIGHT_OR_MULTIPLIER,0)) AS BaseMediumEH`

Comment: its part of query, when I remove this part from actual query then the query it works. Also, I am trying your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You miss two table alias :

Replace *****TableAlias***** by the table alias name you need to do your join.

```
 select 
    v.City,
    v.CURRENCY, 
    (
    select 
        Sum(VSDEH.NORM_PRICE_MEDIUM*BCIEH.WEIGHT_OR_MULTIPLIER) AS BaseMedium

        FROM (
        // This line has error ->> ([VSURVEYDATA] AS VSDEH INNER JOIN [BASKET_CONTENT_ITEMS] AS BCIEH ON VSDEH.ITEM = BCIEH.ITEM_ID) *****TableAlias*****
                      INNER JOIN  [EXCHANGE_RATES] AS EXREH  on VSDEH.SURVEY_DATE = EXREH.RATE_DATE AND VSDEH.CURRENCY = EXREH.BASE_CURRENCY_ID
                   )

        WHERE (
        VSDEH.SURVEY_DATE = v.SURVEY_DATE 
        AND BCIEH.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ID='ICOL' 
        AND BCIEH.BASKET_ID= b.BASKET_ID
        AND BCIEH.ITEM_ID not in ( '215','216','326')
        AND EXREH.HOST_CURRENCY_ID= ex.HOST_CURRENCY_ID
        AND EXREH.RATE_SET_ID=' '
        AND VSDEH.CITY in (v.City)
        )
        GROUP BY VSDEH.CITY, VSDEH.CURRENCY 

    ) as BaseMediumEH

        FROM ((
    ([VSURVEYDATA] AS VSDEH INNER JOIN [BASKET_CONTENT_ITEMS] AS BCIEH ON VSDEH.ITEM = BCIEH.ITEM_ID)  *****TableAlias*****
    INNER JOIN  [EXCHANGE_RATES] AS EXREH  on VSDEH.SURVEY_DATE = EXREH.RATE_DATE AND VSDEH.CURRENCY = EXREH.BASE_CURRENCY_ID
    )

    INNER JOIN qSTAHostCity ON VSURVEYDATA.CITY = qSTAHostCity.HostCity)

        WHERE (
              v.SURVEY_DATE = [Survey Date]  
              AND b.LINE_OF_BUSINESS_ID='ICOL' 
              AND b.BASKET_ID= [Basket ID]
              AND ex.HOST_CURRENCY_ID='USD'
              AND ex.RATE_SET_ID=' ')

        GROUP BY v.CITY, v.CURRENCY ORDER BY v.CITY
```